# Matching User Taxonomy Selections to Related Content

Tags: users

In Drupal 7, I am using the “Profile 2” module to collect information about users.  I am using Profile 2 instead of the core profile functionality because I would like separate pages for users to answer questions.

Basically, users just select taxonomy terms as answers to questions.  For example, there might be a question like “what kinds of skills do you want?” and the user could select “fixing cars” (the taxonomy term and the vocabulary “Skills”.

I would then like to have a view on the user account page that shows recent pieces of content tagged with the term they selected (say, the content type could be called “Jobs”, with a tag within it for “fixing cars”).

Ideally, I would like this view to show all of the related tags a piece of content has to a user, but for now, I just want to figure out this basic functionality.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm looking to do something very similar by matching needs with wants.

Comment: unfortunately not yet - let me know if you find anything as well.

Comment: I think this might be a lead - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454507/creating-list-of-similar-nodes-in-drupal-7-views-3